# Elementor issue

Tags: wordpress, plugins, elementor

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to
Elementor\Core\DynamicTags\Manager::get_tag_data_content() must be of the type array,
null given in /home/customer/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/dynamic-tags/manager.php:219 
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Elementor\Core\DynamicTags\Manager->get_tag_data_content('', 'site-logo', NULL)
#1 /home/customer/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/dynamic-tags/manager.php(123): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /home/customer/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/dynamic-tags/manager.php(84): Elementor\Core\DynamicTags\Manager->parse_tag_text('[elementor-tag ...', Array, Array)
#3 /home/customer/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/controls/base-data.php(81): Elementor\Core\DynamicTags\Manager->parse_tags_text('[elementor-tag ...', Array, Array)
#4 /home/customer/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/bas in /home/customer/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/dynamic-tags/manager.php on line 219
```

Comment: Can you enter the Elementor Editor? Try to set the Site Logo in the Site Settings or in the Costumizer. Do you the Elementor header and which theme is active?

Comment: Hi @Fleks what should I do to the logo to fix this issue?
I am using elementor creating header and footer.